# How to fix the error: camelot' has no attribute "read_pdf"

Tags: python-3.x, python-camelot

I am working in PyCharm, I am facing this problem and can't fix it.

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf('table.pdf')
print(tables)
```

[image]

Error message:
AttributeError: module 'camelot' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

the code is supposed to read tables from the specified PDF file and extract it.

Comment: Did you install the correct camelot package? https://pypi.org/project/camelot-py/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you installed the wrong module. First uninstall the incorrect module by using `pip uninstall camelot`

**Step 1 :** `pip install camelot-py`
**Step 2 :** If you facePdfFileReader deprecated error then `pip install --upgrade PyPDF2==2.12.1`